# CPU softlock ubuntu 22.04.1 Ryzen 5800x3d

Tags: kernel, crash, cpu, gpu

I have been in a fortunate position to allow me to buy a 6800xt gpu and a 5800x3d cpu. I installed these and have carried out a fresh install of Ubuntu however I am running into some softlock issues and some hardware errors.

I was hoping that someone from this forum might have some insight into this issue.

Before installing this hardware the machine was running fine.

Asides from this I have the following specs

650w PSU
MSI B450M motherboard
DDR4 memory ran at 3600mhz
Wifi and bluetoothe pcie x1 adapter

I am running kernel 5.15.0-25-generic

I am running Ubuntu version 22.04.1 LTS

Here is the output from journalctl -b -1 -e

Nov 19 04:02:43 comp-MS-7B84 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:27:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: time out after 2000ms.

Nov 19 04:02:43 comp-MS-7B84 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:27:00.0: Current CMD queue read_ptr 44 write_ptr 45

Nov 19 04:02:48 comp-MS-7B84 kernel: [drm] Fence fallback timer expired on ring gfx_0.0.0

Nov 19 04:02:48 comp-MS-7B84 kernel: [drm] Fence fallback timer expired on ring sdma3

Nov 19 04:02:49 comp-MS-7B84 kernel: [drm] Fence fallback timer expired on ring gfx_0.0.0

Nov 19 04:02:49 comp-MS-7B84 kernel: [drm] Fence fallback timer expired on ring gfx_0.0.0

Nov 19 04:02:49 comp-MS-7B84 kernel: [drm] Fence fallback timer expired on ring sdma2

Nov 19 04:02:50 comp-MS-7B84 kernel: [drm] Fence fallback timer expired on ring gfx_0.0.0

Nov 19 04:02:50 comp-MS-7B84 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:27:00.0: Queue 5 is stuck 35 123

Nov 19 04:02:51 comp-MS-7B84 kernel: [drm] Fence fallback timer expired on ring gfx_0.0.0

Nov 19 04:02:51 comp-MS-7B84 kernel: [drm] Fence fallback timer expired on ring gfx_0.0.0

Nov 19 04:02:52 comp-MS-7B84 gnome-shell[1263]: libinput error: event6  - Logitech G305:

client bug: event processing lagging behind by 604ms, your system is too slow

Nov 19 04:02:52 comp-MS-7B84 gnome-shell[1263]: libinput error: client bug: timer event6

debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-176ms), your system is too slow

Nov 19 04:02:52 comp-MS-7B84 gnome-shell[1263]: libinput error: event5  - Keychron

Keychron K6 Pro Keyboard: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 201ms, your system is too slow

Nov 19 04:02:52 comp-MS-7B84 kernel: [drm] Fence fallback timer expired on ring gfx_0.0.0

Nov 19 04:02:52 comp-MS-7B84 kernel: [drm] Fence fallback timer expired on ring sdma0

Nov 19 04:02:52 comp-MS-7B84 kernel: [drm] Fence fallback timer expired on ring gfx_0.0.0

Nov 19 04:02:58 comp-MS-7B84 kernel: [drm] Fence fallback timer expired on ring gfx_0.0.0

Nov 19 04:03:04 comp-MS-7B84 kernel: [drm] Fence fallback timer expired on ring sdma0

Nov 19 04:03:04 comp-MS-7B84 kernel: [drm] Fence fallback timer expired on ring gfx_0.0.0

Nov 19 04:03:04 comp-MS-7B84 kernel: [drm] Fence fallback timer expired on ring sdma0

Nov 19 04:03:01 comp-MS-7B84 systemd-resolved[682]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of UDP+EDNS0 for DNS server 89.101.160.5.

Nov 19 04:03:11 comp-MS-7B84 kernel: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [swapper/0:0]
~

I am consistently able to recreate this lockup when launching steam, but it is also happening spontaneously.

On reboot I can see the following hardware errors

mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 5: Machine Check:0 bank 5: bea0000000
mce [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR ffffffc0bc0d02 MISC d0120001000
mcd: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:a20f12 Time 1668830606 SOCKET 0 APIC a microcode a201205

I am really not sure where to progress here, I was very much looking forward to using this kit, I understand that the hardware is supported so I was expecting a plug and play.

I experienced a similar cpu error when initially setting up ubuntu using an r9270x (old gpu). I had to enable pitcairn/southern island support in GRUB to remove this issue. I have not seen anything similar for an rx 6800xt and I am under the presumption that ubuntu auto detects the hardware in use. glxinfo does return the correct information about the gpu and lscpu is also correct about the cpu installed.

Any help in resolving this would be much appreciated. I am going to try and install a barebones windows tomorrow and see if I can get the hardware working there.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked your vendor for any firmware updates?

Comment: In addition to firmware updates, it will be important to check that the RAM timings are correct. If you have the power curve settings too high in the BIOS/UEFI, that can also cause issues. The `X` series of AMD CPUs are a bit sensitive with regards to power delivery. Windows compensates by over-volting by a few percent. Linux will not do this automatically.